# zsh function to set docker environment on OSX

Tags: macos, shell, docker, zsh

I am trying to create a function in zsh to run the command `docker-machine env <machine>` for the current machine if there is only one machine running.  I am trying to get it to run the following eval command:

`eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`

To set the docker environment variables, running `docker-machine env default` will output the following:

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/chris/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

So, to set the environment correctly, you need to enter `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`

I have the following function

```
dmset() {
    COUNT=`docker-machine ls | grep "Running" | wc -l`
    if [[ "${COUNT// /}" == "1" ]]
    then
        RUNNING_MACHINE=`docker-machine ls | grep "Running" | awk '{print $1;}'`
        COMMAND="\"\$(docker-machine env $RUNNING_MACHINE)\""
        eval $COMMAND
        echo Setting docker environment for $RUNNING_MACHINE
    else
        echo "Unable to set Docker environment"
    fi
}
```

but this is not working.  I get the following error message:

```
(eval):1: no such file or directory: export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"\nexport DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"\nexport DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/chris/.docker/machine/machines/default"\nexport DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"\n# Run this command to configure your shell: \n# eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

how can I run the eval command to set the environment via a single script?

Comment: Its unclear what you expect to happen. Can you edit you Q to include examples of what you expect to happen inside `eval $COMMAND`? I have years of experience using `eval` and I don't see what it can do for you in this case (and have for several years discarded `eval` for more modern syntax). ... AND why the mix of backticked commands vs `$( modern cmd substitution)`. Join the 1990's and embrace `$(modern cmd substitution)` :-)! Good luck!

Comment: There is probably a better way to do it, but running docker to configure the environment docker-machine env <machine> says to run the eval statement.  But I can't get the eval to run properly... not that I really understand eval properly.

Comment: Don't put complex commands inside strings. It doesn't work well (or at all in most cases). Just don't do it.

Comment: Would evaluating the result of `dme=$(tr '\n' ';' < $(docker-machine env default))`; eval "${dme}" be better? (replacing newlines with semicolons). Quotes within `$dme` might need to be escaped though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @Etan Reisner's comment, I changed it to:

```
dmset() {
    COUNT=`docker-machine ls | grep "Running" | wc -l`
    if [[ "${COUNT// /}" == "1" ]]
    then
        RUNNING_MACHINE=`docker-machine ls | grep "Running" | awk '{print $1;}'`
        while IFS= read -r line
        do
            if [[ $line == 'export'* ]]
            then
                eval $line
            fi
        done < <(docker-machine env $RUNNING_MACHINE)
        echo "Docker environment set for $RUNNING_MACHINE"
    else
        echo "Unable to set Docker environment"
    fi
}
```